# ¿Cómo personalizar botón con forma redondeada en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Necesito aplicar a mi formulario la siguiente imagen a un  botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es como hacer que el botón se adecue a la imagen, con los bordes redondos, y que al ubicar el cursor sobre el mismo no se vean las extremidades en forma de punta.

Comment: Una manera facil seria poner un picturebox con una imagen en forma de boton con los bordes redondos y establecerle el evento click para que funcione como button

Comment: Usa WPF ya que en el axml puedes personalizar la forma en que se verá tu botón más fácilmente permitiéndote los bordes redondeados y los tipos de letra así como el fondo del botón por ejemplo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745663/how-to-create-make-rounded-corner-buttons-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice el usuario Técnica Aplicada creo que lo mas fácil es usar un picturebox:

-Cambia el `backcolor` a transparente.

-Cambia el valor `Image` por la imagen de tu botón (en formato png por ejemplo para que no se vea el fondo transparente)

-Aplícale los eventos `mouseClick`, `mouseHover` y `mouseLeave` para que tenga un comportamiento similar a un botón.

Te dejo un ejemplo de botón configurado en el .designer:

```
  this.btnJugar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
  this.btnJugar.Image = ruta
  resources.ApplyResources(this.btnJugar, "btnJugar");
  this.btnJugar.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.btnJugar_MouseClick);
  this.btnJugar.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.btnJugar_MouseLeave);
  this.btnJugar.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.btnJugar_MouseHover);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para futuras visitas a esta pregunta, chequeen este [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122509/como-cambiar-la-forma-a-los-botones-en-windows-forms-c), aquí consiguen un control con el cual pueden personalizar los botones de su aplicación.

Espero sea de ayuda.

***Saludos!***

Comment: David, es posible que en el futuro el link pueda dejar de funcionar. Para evitar esto y mantener la calidad del sitio, considera [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la informacion.