# ¿Como cambiar la forma a los botones en Windows Forms c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Alguien tiene idea de como hacer que la forma de los botones por default de Windows Forms cambie? 
Por ejemplo un boton redondo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En Windows Forms (Winforms) vas a tener que utilizar controles de terceros, o si quieres crear el tuyo tienes que heredar de la clase Button y sobrecargar el método OnPaint, por ejemplo:

```
public class BtnRedondo : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsPath grPath = new GraphicsPath();
        grPath.AddEllipse(0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(grPath);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Pero yo recomiendo mejor buscar alguna librería de terceros con controles que cumplan con lo que requieres, busca en Github.com o en CodeProject, por ejemplo aquí tienes uno: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15730/RoundButton-Windows-Control-Ever-Decreasing-Circle

O mejor aun, utilizar WPF, que tiene muchísima mas libertad en el diseño de controles, Winforms es una tecnología bastante anticuada.

Answer (score 2):

Como se plantea en la respuesta anterior, puedes usar librerías de terceros.

**Otra forma puede ser creando tu propio estilo de botón.**

> Puedes hacerlo haciendo uso de un [UserControl (Control de Usuario)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) , el cual puedes heredar de la [Clase Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx)

Aquí un ejemplo **Básico** puedes establecer  la propiedad `FlatStyle: Flat` del botón. Aquí lo que haces es que asignas una imagen al botón dependiendo de:

1. Si el usuario pasa el mouse encima del botón
2. Si el usuario deja el mouse encima del botón
3. Si el usuario hace click encima del botón.
4. ....

es algo muy básico, solo es un ejemplo.

```
    public partial class BotonPersonalizado: Button
    {
        public BotonPersonalizado()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Implementar todos los métodos y propiedades que desees...

        private void Boton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           Boton.BackgroundImage = NombreProyecto.Properties.Resources.Tuimagen;
        }

        private void Boton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Boton.BackgroundImage = NombreProyecto.Properties.Resources.Tuimagen;
        }

        private void Boton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Boton.BackgroundImage = NombreProyecto.Properties.Resources.Tuimagen;
        }

        private void Boton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           Boton.BackgroundImage = NombreProyecto.Properties.Resources.Tuimagen;
        }
    }
```

Al heredar de la clase button, el **control de usuario** cuenta con todas las propiedades que contiene un botón y podrás utilizar ese Botón cuantas veces quieras en todos los formularios.

El botón personalizado se agregará al **Cuadro de Herramientas (Toolbox)**